# Slow SQLDataReader GetString

Tags: .net, sqldatareader

On one row rdr.GetString takes 12-15 seconds

A couple rows takes 4 - 5 seconds
A few take 1-4 seconds
Most rows are are less than 100 milliseconds

The whole query only returns 3,286 rows and runs in 15 seconds in SSMS

[Value] is varchar(600) - nothing special about it that I know of
There is an index on [fieldID], [value] that was rebuilt (several times)

In SqlDataReader reading row 208  takes 12 - 15 seconds
Reading that one row takes as long as reading all of the remaining 3,285 rows

If I change sort on [fieldID] to desc then it hangs on row 2050
And that is not the same row (it is not even the same [fieldID])

Before the rdr.GetString is a rdr.GetByte and it never hangs on the GetByte. 
It already has the row!
Even hitting another server with similar but not exact database it also hangs.

I know this sounds crazy but it is happening. 
It feels like SqlDataReader is hanging but I use SqlDataReader all the time in this app and returning a lot more rows than this.

If I do a manual GC.Collect() when fieldID changes it still hangs on mostly the same rows. 
The times of the individual hangs are a little smaller but the total is about the same.  Using a threshold of 1 second might have one that is just in or just out but the problems rows definitely repeat.

Thought it might be related to number of characters between hangs but is can be as low as 600 and as high as 60,000.

But it does appear to be related to the data returned. 
If I exclude or include [rownumber] (and don't read it) it will hang on different rows. 
But the rows are in the same vicinity.

```
 fieldID = rdr.GetByte(0);    // this line does not hang
 delta = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
 textValue = rdr.GetString(1);  // this is the line that hang on some rows 
 if ((sw.ElapsedMilliseconds - delta) > 1000L)
    Debug.WriteLine("GabeLib_Helper sw in  fields  thisFieldID = " + thisFieldID + " counter = " + counter + " ccount = " + ccount + " after getstring read delta = " + (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds - delta).ToString("N0") + " textValue = " + textValue);

select [fieldID], [value], [rowNum]
from 
(
SELECT [fieldID], ltrim(rtrim([value])) as [value]
     , ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by [fieldID] order by ltrim(rtrim([value])) ) as [rowNum]
  FROM [docSVtext] with (nolock)
  JOIN [docFieldDef] with (nolock)
    ON [docFieldDef].[ID] = [fieldID] 
   AND [docFieldDef].[typeID] in (101) 
   AND [docFieldDef].[active] =  'true' 
   AND len(ltrim(rtrim([value]))) > 0 and len(ltrim(rtrim([value]))) <= 200 
  JOIN [docSVsys] with (nolock) 
    on [docSVsys].[sID] = [docSVtext].[sID] 
   and [docSVsys].[visibility] = 0 
 group by [fieldID], ltrim(rtrim([value]))
 ) as withRow
 where [rowNum] < 1001
 order by [fieldID], [rowNum]
```

If I add rdr.GetInt64(2); above rdr.GetString(1);
Then it hangs on rdr.GetInt64(2); and does not hang on rdr.GetString(1);
And with rdr.GetInt64(2); I am getting one slow rdr.Read().

```
delta = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds; 
rowNum = rdr.GetInt64(2);
if ((sw.ElapsedMilliseconds - delta) > 1000L)
    Debug.WriteLine("GabeLib_Helper sw in  fields  in PastEntries new rowNum  rdr.GetInt64(2) " + rowNum + " counter = " + counter + " ccount = " + ccount + "  delta = " + (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds - delta).ToString("N0"));
```

The query below runs in 2 seconds in SSMS
This is not the problem query
Included to show the indexes appears to be working

```
  select fieldID, value, count(*)  
  from docSVtext 
  group by fieldID, value
```

I tracked GC and it is not related to the slow downs
Even when GC runs it only take 20 ms

```
delta = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
List<int> gcCounts = new List<int>();
for (int g = 0; g <= GC.MaxGeneration; g++) gcCounts.Add(GC.CollectionCount(g));
textValue = rdr.GetString(1);  //  " Chen, Andy </O=ENRON/OU=NA/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=ACHEN>" + Guid.NewGuid(); //
if ((sw.ElapsedMilliseconds - delta) > 100L)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("GabeLib_Helper sw in  fields  thisFieldID = " + thisFieldID + " counter = " + counter + " ccount = " + ccount + " after getstring read delta = " + (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds - delta).ToString("N0") + " textValue = " + textValue);

}
for (int g = 0; g <= GC.MaxGeneration; g++)
{
    if (GC.CollectionCount(g) != gcCounts[g])
        Debug.WriteLine("GabeLib_Helper GC new count = " + GC.CollectionCount(g) + " old count =" + gcCounts[g] + " generation " + g + " ccount = " + ccount + " after getstring read delta = " + (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds - delta).ToString("N0"));
}
```

Comment: @Rhumborl But it is hanging on GetString - how is that a misnomer?  And it has not problem if I assign textValue to as hard coded  "value"

Comment: Is the 1st query the one causing the problem? i.e `order by fieldID, rownum` with `desc` added to it? If so, try removing 'ltrim(rtrim(..))` in the `order by` clause of subquery.

Comment: @shahkalpesh Did not fix the problem.  It now hangs on different rows.  As I stated the query runs just fine in SSMS.  And it has already performed a rdr.GetByte(0) on that row with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out

If I remove the

```
where [rowNum] < 1001
```

Then is does not have any long row reads
The query takes longer as now it reads every row
That hang is when it was skipping past those rows
Since the the actual reader is ahead of the read it was hard to see that

But no problem in SSMS still confuses me

tried a

```
select ID, count(*) 
  from table 
  ...
group by ID 
having count(*) > x
```

To only query for the ID that were under the x count
Problem is query took a few second to run

What I ended up doing is

```
select top (x + 1), value 
  from table 
 where ID = i1
 group by value;
select top (x + 1), value 
  from table 
 where ID = i2
 group by value;
...
```

if the count get up to x + 1 then I don't use it

What was happening is some really big count where eating up a lot of time and I did not even want those.  Even getting the count of a big count was expensive